# Read a line in java and then tokenize it

Tags: java, line

I am looking for easiest way to read a line in Java. Once read, I want to tokenize the line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Read it from where? Scan it for what?

Comment: like this:http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: Don't use `StringTokenizer`; `Scanner` is now preferred.

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.util.*;

//...

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = sc.nextLine();
if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
  int i = sc.nextInt();
  //...
}
```

[`java.util.Scanner API`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

- It can take a `File`, `InputStream`, and `String` as source (among other things)

  - `new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))`
  - `new Scanner("some string you want to tokenize")`
- You can also set custom delimiter

  - `sc.useDelimiter(";")`
- Supports regex too

  - `sc.next("[a-z]+")`

---

Elsewhere on stackoverflow:

- [Java’s Scanner vs String.split() vs StringTokenizer; which should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736654/javas-scanner-vs-string-split-vs-stringtokenizer-which-should-i-use)
- [How to read integer value from the standard input in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506077/how-to-read-integer-value-from-the-standard-input-in-java/2506109#2506109)
- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

Comment: Is Scanner better than BufferedReader?

Comment: You may want to combine `BufferedReader` with `Scanner` if you insist on reading a line _and then_ tokenizing it, but `Scanner` lets you tokenize a line as you're reading it, so in some cases that simplifies things.

Answer (score 2):

[`FileUtils.readLines(..)`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29) from [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/)

Then use `String.split(regex)` rather than a tokenizer.

Comment: Disadvantage of this is that you need a third-party library.