# Parsing a string to split into two names

Tags: java, string, parsing

Take a String parameter that is a name, with exactly two names in the String and exactly one space between the two names.

For example, "Marley, Bob"

I need help completing this method: it returns a String with the same name, but in the form "Bob Marley"

```
public static String convertName(String name) 
{

}
```

Comment: Another homework? What did you try?

Comment: Many things, all of which did not work :) I'm not a slacker, I'm still learning.

Comment: @ReneaS. Then show it. Say if you did something like String.replace(","," "). Not only could someone explain WHAT to do to fix it but teach you WHY yours didn't work, giving you two benefits. Right now instead you have two poor submitted answers now and may have to fix theirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] arr = name.split(", ");
return arr[1]+" "+arr[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

I will use a StringTokenizer and StringBuilder for this problem

```
public static String convertName(String name) 
{
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(name, ", ");
    String lastName = tokenizer.nextToken();
    String firstName = tokenizer.nextToken();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("\nfirstName : " + firstName);
    builder.append("\nlastName : " + lastName);
    return builder.toString();                  
}
```

Comment: I did some research on this, and it seems after JDK 1.4, the use of StringTokenizer to split String in Java is discouraged, and instead the String.split(...) method or use of java.util.regex package is encouraged.

Comment: You can do a perfomance test to see which one is faster, split() or tokenizer for one line and many lines; reference:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736654/javas-scanner-vs-string-split-vs-stringtokenizer-which-should-i-use

Comment: nextElement() does not return a String…..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#nextElement()  @openmike If speed matters, one would just iterate over the String.

Comment: I made changes to tokenizer.nextToken(). Sorry about that.

Comment: Renea: performance test for a case where you have many lines of each full name and you have to call that method multiple times using an iterator or loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Apache Commons** libraries provide great solutions unless you've specific requirements.

Have `Commons Lang` jar in your classpath. The following snippet may be the needed solution [doesn't look so elegant though].

```
StringUtils.replace(StringUtils.reverseDelimited(name, ','), ",", " ")
```

`StringUtils.reverseDelimited(name, delimiter)` 
- Reverses the order identified by delimiter.
Ex: a,b,c becomes c,b,a

`StringUtils.replace(name,searchString, replaceString)` - Replaces all occurences of searchString with replaceString

Refer API - [StringUtils - Commons Lang 2.6](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

Comment: This won't wrap the first and last name!

Comment: @bobbel I didn't get your point. The input is "Bob, Marley" and output needs to be "Bob Marley" as per the method declaration & OP's question.

Comment: Read it clearly: 'Marley, Bob' should turn into 'Bob Marley'!

Comment: @bobbel Thanks bobbel! Overlooked & corrected now.