# using scanner to evaluate words in a string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Im trying to write a method that returns the number of words from the "words" parameter that have at least the min" but no more than the "max c"haracters.

```
public static int countWords(String words, int min, int max)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner (words);
    int counter = 0;

 while  (s.hasNext())
    {
    String word = s.next();
    int wordLength = word.length();
    if (wordLength>min && wordLength<max)
    {
        counter= counter + 1;
        s.close();
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: It is totally unclear to me what you are asking. your English wording is very confusing. what is the issue? where is the error?

Comment: Can you translate this for me? "Im trying to write a method that returns the number of words from the "words" parameter that have at least the min" but no more than the "max c"haracters."

Comment: lol, I copy and pasted the instructions just as I was told. But Im trying to find the words in a string (words) that have at least a certain amount of characters (min) and no more than certain amount of characters (max). hope that makes more sense

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: my instructor  gave test cases and there is something wrong with it according to those test cases so I was hoping to get some help

Comment: so tell me what is wrong? at least post up some error code?

Comment: that us the thing, there is no error code except that showed by the test cases which is is that the output expected was 3 but 0 was given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61019/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-gamaliel-tellez-ortiz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can understand from you, you want to count words that has specified max and min

For example,

`"The rain in Spain falls mainly in the plain", 3, 5`  is return `5` because they are 3 fives and 2 threes

your code is quite alright except this part which needs some change in its logic

```
if (wordLength>min && wordLength<max)
```

Based on what I understand from your question you want word which has either min length or max length

As result you have to change that if statement to this

```
if (wordLength == min || wordLength == max) {
```

**Explanation** : length of the word is equal to min length or max length , counter is gonna be added

Comment: How can that be the accepted answer? `wordLength == min || wordLength == max` is not representing 'at least the min" but no more than the "max c"haracters' (unless `min == max-1`) - even back in 2014

Answer (score 1):

Just a small change. You are closing the scanner in the while loop, move it out of the loop and it works.

```
public static int countWords(String words, int min, int max) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(words);
        int counter = 0;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            String word = s.next();
            int wordLength = word.length();
            if (wordLength > min && wordLength < max) {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
        s.close();
        return counter;
    }
```

And also I suggest, you change the if condition to make it inclusive of min and max.
if (wordLength >= min && wordLength =< max) {
For example countWords("count words in this line 1 22 333 4444 55555",3,4) would not return any result for any string with you current condition.

Answer (score 1):

The preference of using split versus scanner while working with Strings has been discussed before in

- [Java's Scanner vs String.split() vs StringTokenizer; which should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736654/javas-scanner-vs-string-split-vs-stringtokenizer-which-should-i-use)

I prefer regex, so here is a solution using the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method of String as follows:

### Using regex

```
public class Sample {
    
    public static int countWords(String words, int min, int max) {

        String[] allWords = words.split("(?s)\\s+");
        int counter = 0;

        for (String word : allWords) {
            if(word.length() >= min && word.length() <= max)
                counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "find all the long words in this sentence";
        System.out.println(countWords(s,4,7));
    }
}
```

If you want to use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), you can do it like this :

### Using scanner

```
public class Sample {
    
    public static int countWords(String words, int min, int max) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(words);
        int counter = 0;
        int length = 0;

        while(scan.hasNext()){
            length  = scan.next().length();
            if(length >= min && length <= max)
                counter++;
        }
        scan.close();
        return counter;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "find all the long words in this sentence";
        System.out.println(countWords(s,4,7));
    }
}
```