# Is StringTokenizer still recommended for USACO?

Tags: java, parsing

I am just beginning to tackle some USACO practice problems using Java. However, I've immediately encountered some confusion regarding parsing file input...

The USACO training pages say:

> Important: BufferedReader and StringTokenizer are far more efficient
>   than many other schemes for reading input. They can make a huge
>   difference in the efficiency of your program! Use them!

However, the Oracle docs say:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.

I am finding very mixed opinions on the internet. Some, including the training pages, say that `StringTokenizer` should be used because it's faster than `String.split()` which is faster than `Scanner` (though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16573673/4727735) answer disagrees). Others say `Scanner` or `String.split()` should be used because they're simpler to use and because the performance cost from parsing files is negligible.

Which method is the most practical as of now?

Comment: [This IDEOne](http://ideone.com/yjT5j3) should give you an idea of the performance difference. `StringTokenizer` appears to be much faster, but speed isn't everything. No one wants you to write code for them that needs to be updated in a year because it doesn't work with the new JDK release.

Comment: `Scanner` is effective, easy to use and usually performant enough for the needs of programming competitions.

Answer (score 4):

In programming competitions, the logic and algorithmic part of your code is more important than the method you use to get input data.

There are only a few milliseconds of difference between `Scanner` and `StringTokenizer` which does not impact your solution in any major way.

In general, however, Scanner is easier to use and performs consistently well whereas (you stated) StringTokenizer is a legacy class and its use is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way for Java USACO is `BufferedReader` and `StringTokenizer`. `Scanner` and `.split()` are less efficient.

Let's say we want to input `3 5`, two numbers, `N M`.

```java
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
int N = Integer.parseInt(st.nextInt())
int M = Integer.parseInt(st.nextInt())
```

Inefficient Way Would Be:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.i));
String[] s = scanner.next().split(" ");
int N = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
int M = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
```

USACO Solutions for Java on their official website prefer `BufferedReader` and `StringTokenizer` instead of `String.split()` or `Scanner`.